# What is the purpose of a private nested/inner class?

Tags: java, class, private

I was under impression that a private inner/nested class is only used for/by/accessed by outer class. But experimenting I realized that the HashSet(which is not the outer class of Happy) can access the class. If so then what is the real use of `private` ? Is it only restricting *creation* of classes to within outer class ?

```
public class FreeMain {

    private static class Happy {
       int x; 
       private Happy(int x) {
           this.x = x;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           return 10;
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Happy> happiness = new HashSet<Happy>();

        Happy h1 = new Happy(10);
        Happy h2 = new Happy(20);

        happiness.add(h1);
        happiness.add(h2);
    }   
}
```

Comment: been a while, but  the class HashSet wouldn't be able to stick its nose into FreeMain and access a private class or variable within it(along the lines of class.variable or class.innerclass. But I suppose(untested) if you created an instance of your private class and passed that to somebody, then it'd work with it.  and when I learnt java, long ago, it didn't have Set<...> so I dunno re that.

Comment: Even *what* HashSet? What's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Access modifiers in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) control the *scope* in which an identifier can be legally accessed or referenced. You are using your private nested (static => nested, non-static => inner) class as the type parameter to a `HashSet`—but the reference is still happening within the scope of the parent class.

> If so then what is the real use of Private ? Is it only restricting creation of classes to within outer class ?

No, it doesn't just restrict creation. You can't even reference the type `Happy` outside the `FreeMain` class. If you try to declare something with type `Happy`, or use `Happy` as a type parameter (like `Set<Happy>`) outside class `FreeMain`, you'll get a compiler error.

---

> To summarize, if reference to private nested class is passed to another class(like set), it works so long as its in scope of freemain.

Yes, that's basically correct. However, the type isn't really being "passed" to `Set` when you declare a `Set<Happy>`. None of the code in the `Set` class ever sees the actual type you provide in the parameter (due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)). The Java compiler just uses the information you specify in the type parameters as a kind of type assertion to check the correctness of your program.

When you declare `Set<Happy> happiness`, the fact that the `happiness` contains `Happy` instances is not known anywhere but within the scope of `happiness`. Therefore, the `Happy` type is never actually used outside the scope of your `FreeMain` class, and that's why it's legal even though `Happy` is private.

Comment: To summarize, if reference to private nested class is passed to another class(like set), it works so long as its in scope of freemain.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper - Yes, that's basically correct. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Compelling reasons for using nested classes include the following:

It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place: If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.

It increases encapsulation: Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden from the outside world.

It can lead to more readable and maintainable code: Nesting small classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is used.

Comment: My question is whats the benefit / use of making the inner/nested class a private class. Thanks for answer but question was different one.